# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. - sites not using MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using mysql connection for a asp.net web application. So i installed mysql-connector-net-6.9.7.msi. Everything working fine for that project.
So I deployed that on web server and installed that mysql connector as well.
The application with MySQL connection works fine but other websites on web server are throwing error:
'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
(.net 4.0, EF 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yourserver don't have 6.9.7 mysql connector , try installing 6.3.7 mysql connector on your server or use Entity framework 6

Comment: Thanks Akash but there is 6.9.7 mysql connector. The error was thrown from other sites which do not use that connector. The site which use that connector is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

after two hours in internet i resolved this issue by removing sitemap section in machine.config file.
Thank you so much